# An object's Position $P$ changes so that its distance from $(1,2,-3)$ is always twice its distance from $(1,2,3).$ Show $P$ is on a sphere.

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

An object's Position $P$ changes so that its distance from $(1,2,-3)$ is always twice its distance from $(1,2,3).$ Show $P$ is on a sphere. Find its center and radius.

If $A(1,2,-3)$ and $P (x,y,z),$ the distance $AP =\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+3)^2}.$

If $B(1,2,3)$ and $P(x,y,z),$ the distance $BP =\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-3)^2}.$

So, 
$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+3)^2} = 2\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-3)^2}$$ 
$$(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+3)^2 = 4\big[(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-3)^2\big]$$

I did until there but how can I have an equation of the sphere , center and radius?

Comment: You want to try type setting using [Latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: sorry I want to but I don't know how

Comment: Click on the blue hyperlink in the word Latex in my previous comment. It will take you to a page that will show you how.

Answer (score 1):

From:

$$(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z+3)^2 = 4[(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-3)^2]$$

we get 
$$ 3(x-1)^2+3(y-2)^2+3z^2-30z+27=0$$

so 
$$ (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-5)^2=16$$

So the center of this sphere is at $(1,2,4)$ and radius is $4$.

Comment: Have you upvoted?@cyan